# Как разобрать xml в цикле

Tags: php, xml

Здравствуйте.
У меня такая проблема. Есть xml, часть которого я привожу тут

```
            <Предложение>
            <Ид>c71767b4-201a-11e7</Ид>
            <Артикул>ББ000002161</Артикул>
            <Наименование>Смеситель тюльпан НЕПТУН </Наименование>
            <БазоваяЕдиница Код="796" НаименованиеПолное="Штука" МеждународноеСокращение="">шт</БазоваяЕдиница>
            <Цены>
                <Цена>
                    <Представление>3 001,2 KZT за шт</Представление>
                    <ИдТипаЦены>e3f0b147</ИдТипаЦены>
                    <ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>3001.2</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
                    <Валюта>KZT</Валюта>
                    <Единица>шт</Единица>
                    <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                </Цена>
                <Цена>
                    <Представление>5 875 KZT за шт</Представление>
                    <ИдТипаЦены>e3f0b146</ИдТипаЦены>       
                    <ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>5875</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
                    <Валюта>KZT</Валюта>
                    <Единица>шт</Единица>
                    <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                </Цена>
                <Цена>
                    <Представление>4 775 KZT за шт</Представление>
                    <ИдТипаЦены>e3f0b14a</ИдТипаЦены>        
                    <ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>4775</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
                    <Валюта>KZT</Валюта>
                    <Единица>шт</Единица>
                    <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                </Цена>
            </Цены>
            <Количество>146</Количество>
        </Предложение>
```

Я получаю файл с помощью

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($dir . $filename);
```

и нужно его распарсить в цикле, то есть вытащить два из нескольких значений  `<ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>` у которых `<ИдТипаЦены>` равен определённой переменной.

По идее, надо просто перебрать в цикле `$xml_variant->Цены->Цена`, проверить в каждом из них `<ИдТипаЦены>` и вытащить необходимые `<ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>`

Но foreach `($xml_variant->Цены->Цена as $value)` выдаёт ошибку.

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Какую ошибку то выдает? сделайте `var_dump($xml_variant->Цены->Цена)`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй:

```
foreach ($xml_variant->{Цены}->{Цена} as $value) {
  var_dump($value)
}
```